# gnuplot plot the curves in file

Tags: function, graph, plot, gnuplot, curves

I have a file with table to plot, every column in file correspond to one curve

for example, file1

```
N plot1 plot2 plot3

1 2     3     4
2 3     4     5
```

I run the gnuplot as following

`gnuplot -e "set key autotitle columnhead; set title 'file1'; plot 'file1' using 1:2  with lines, 'file1' using 1:3 with lines, 'file1' using 1:4 with lines"`

The problem is if I have a lot of curves to plot, I have a lot of columns I need to describe them in command for gnuplot, however I think it's pretty standard to plot every column file with the first column, like `1:2 1:3 1:4`

Can I do it in more convenient way, without listing all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a forloop, e.g.

```
plot for [i=2:4] "file" using 1:i
```

You need a version of Gnuplot of at least 4.4 for this feature.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, do you know how to make is generic, for example if I have less than 4 curves or more than 4?

Comment: @user16168 I do not really know how to do that.

Comment: You need an external tool to count the number of columns. Try `MAXCOL = int(system('head -1 '.file.' | awk "{print NF}"'))`.